# Simultaneous opening of 2 dropdowns sharing same directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angularjs dropdown directive called X that opens and shows related items when I start typing on an input field. There are two X directives in my page which have the same controller and template (ie same directive but different isolated scope).

The first directive shows list of planets and the second shows list of minerals in the planet that is being typed. When I start typing on an input, I want to open both directive showing related data dynamically. But as they share same template, I don't know how to open the dropdown for the second directive.

There is a single ng-repeat in the template but 2 lists on 2 different scopes. I just want to know the approach in understanding this. Thank you.

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here directive will listen inpVal and updates the list in directive (you need to pass inpVal to the directive).

```
.directive("myCustomSelect", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        scope: {
            inpVal: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs){

            var _list = [];

            scope.list = _list;

            var _watch = scope.$watch("inpVal", function(n){
                if(n){
                    updateList();
                }
            });

            scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
                _watch();
            });

            function updateList(){
                var enteredVal = scope.inpVal;

                //_.filter is underscore js
                scope.list = _.filter(_list, function(v){
                    return enteredVal == v.name?true:false; 
                });                
            }            

        },
        template: "<select ng-options="l.name as l for l in list"></select>"
    }
})
```